# Best way to store developer specific variables in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, environment-variables, development-environment

We have a team of people working on a rails 3.1 app. With each developer we would would like to store a variable in the environment for development which is ignored by git to identify that user. For example

in first developers environment

```
adminuser = "Ryan"
```

and in second developers Development environment

```
adminuser = "Tom"
```

We would use this for developer specific logic within  the app. What is simplest and the best way to implement this and is this the right approach?

Comment: are you using any gem for deployment like capistrano?

Comment: maybe this article could be helpful - http://railsapps.github.com/rails-environment-variables.html

Comment: -- using heroku (reply to maximus)